# CMake passes Visual C++ parameters to clang instead of expexted GCC ones

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clang, mingw

I'm trying to build the project under win10 using mingw latest toolchain and clang compilers (from CLion IDE) with explicitly specified compilers in commandline options :

```
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/dev/tools/LLVM/bin/clang.exe
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/dev/tools/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe
```

cmake recognize clang correctly, but during the test compilations tries to pass cl (Visual C++ compiler) flags:

```
C:\dev\tools\CLion.RC\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/dev/tools/LLVM/bin/clang.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/dev/tools/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\amigo421\ClionProjects\hr2

-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.9.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/dev/tools/LLVM/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/dev/tools/LLVM/bin/clang.exe -- broken CMake Error at
C:/dev/tools/CLion.RC/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61
(message):   The C compiler "C:/dev/tools/LLVM/bin/clang.exe" is not
able to compile a   simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

  C:\dev\tools\LLVM\bin\clang.exe /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 -o  
CMakeFiles\cmTC_397ea.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c  
C:\Users\amigo421\ClionProjects\hr2\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c


  **clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/DWIN32'**

  **clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/D_WINDOWS'**

  **clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/W3'**

  CMakeFiles\cmTC_397ea.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target  
'CMakeFiles/cmTC_397ea.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed

  mingw32-make.exe[1]: ***
[CMakeFiles/cmTC_397ea.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj]   Error 1

  mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory  
'C:/Users/amigo421/ClionProjects/hr2/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
```

you see that cmake passes visual c++ flags , I don't plan to use clang-cl. 
I suppose that cmake should use GCC (MinGW) parameters in command line

any idea how to fix this

Comment: Mixed options styles (`/` and `-`) in single command line... It could be that **the project itself** unconditionally sets the windows-specific flags. Or you use `Visual Studio` generator instead of `MinGW` one (but in this case all options should be windows like, `/`).

Comment: probably cmake "thinks" that clang is cl family compiler

Comment: from the post above, you can see the generator (just scroll to right) -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"

Comment: @amigo421 "cmake recognize clang correctly" -- not really. It only recognises the C++ compiler, not the C one, which then breaks. Notice the "The C compiler identification is unknown" part.

Comment: sorry, it was corrupted cmakecache, next generatings were successful for C and C++ , but with the same issue with compiler's flags, now for C too

Comment: Hi @amigo421 -- did you ever find the answer to this?  I am experiencing these flags getting passed to (g++ for me) can't seem to get Visual Studio to stop trying to pass them...

Comment: unfortunatelly no, I am not working with windows/visual studio for a long time . didn't investigate this more ...